# Safe way to unpack integer values from a remote device

Tags: c++

I get bytes from a remote device via USB protocol. These bytes contain integer data. Is the following code a safe way to unpack them without portability issues (except endianess which is known):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  std::uint8_t someArray[4] = {1,0,0,0};
  std::int32_t someValue = 0;
  std::memcpy(&someValue, someArray, 4);
  
  std::cout << someValue << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This will probably work, but personally I'd solve both the endianess and translation at the same time by assembling result from octets manually. You know its 32bit. You know its (apparently) possibly signed (which is the only part that makes it a little tricky), And I assume you know whether the packer (i.e. the device sending this) is posting it to the bus in network vs host order (i.e. it always be BE on the bus). Given all of that, assembling the octets into a 32bit result should be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

`std::memcpy` is indeed the way to go. In real-life code, I'd `static_assert` on the size of types used and check data size at run-time, but nothing more.